# Viewpager tabs recreated?

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I have implemented a `NavigationDrawer` with a few items in it. Every item represents a different `Fragment` and one of them has tabs. My problem is that every time I open this `Fragment` the tabs reloaded! and added to the previous tabs. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

This is the `Fragment` with the tabs:

```
public class fragment_profilo_tabs extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    String[] tabs = { "Profilo aziendale", "Credenziali" };

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Initilization
                View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.profilo_tabs, null);

                viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
                actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
                mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

                viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
                actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

                // Adding Tabs
                for (String tab_name : tabs) {
                    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                            .setTabListener(this));}

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

And this is my `ViewPagerAdapter`:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getItemPosition(java.lang.Object)
     */

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new fragment_profilo_modificaProfilo();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new fragment_profilo_credenzialiAccesso();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 2;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there are multiple issues. First and foremost lets talk about your `ViewPagerAdapter`:

The first thing that caught my eye is this:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

This is very bad for performance. I know that some posts on Stack Overflow suggest using this to "fix" a few things, but that is not the way to go. Remove this, you don't need it.

---

But the main issue is in your `Fragment`. First and foremost this:

```
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
        .setText(tab_name)
        .setTabListener(this));
}
```

You are adding tabs to the `ActionBar`. And the `ActionBar` is not part of you `Fragment`. Each time you display this `Fragment` you add the same tabs to the `ActionBar` but you never remove them again or anything.

My advice: Don't do this. Open a new `Activity` for the tabs `Fragment`. This should clearly not be in the same `Activity`. I cannot imagine any situation where suddenly adding tabs to the current `Activity` would satisfy the Android Platform Guidelines or provide good usability.

---

The general rule is that everything that has to do with the `Activity` itself - like things concerning the `ActionBar` or tabs in the `ActionBar` - should be handled in the `Activity`. Code which adds tabs to the `ActionBar` has no place inside a `Fragment`. So either add the tabs permanently in `onCreate()` of your `Activity`. Or create a new `Activity` with those tabs especially for the `fragment_profilo_tabs`.

<sub>As an aside: class names should never be [**Snake Case**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). Start class names with an uppercase letter and use [**Camel Case**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). Everything else will just confuse other programmers looking at your code</sub>

Comment: Thanks Xaver,i've try this solution yesterday but how can i start an activity from a drawer?What i think is to use a fragment between the drawer and the activity...is this a correct way?

    @Override
       public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
          
         Intent firstpage= new Intent(getActivity(),fragment_profilo_tabs.class);
           getActivity().startActivity(firstpage);

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You can start an `Activity` from a `NavigationDrawer` just like you can start it anywhere else. Create an `Intent` to the `Activity` and then start it with `startActivity(intent);`.

Comment: Maybe in this way? 
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,destination.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

Comment: Yes that's it. But you know if you are new to Android you should go through [**the official tutorials**](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html).